# I use SQLite manager create a database call test.sqlite. Can I import .sqlite database to xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I use SQLite mananger (Firefox) to create a simple database for testing. The file is test.sqlite.
My question is can I use .sqlite database file in Xcode?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

1) Add a database file into your project. 
2) Go to Target settings and add a link to `libsqlite3.dylib` library 
3) add `#import <sqlite3.h>` 
4) open the database using `sqlite3_open` function

Look other functions [here](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html) or directly in `sqlite3.h`

Comment: Add .db or .sqlite into the project?